# Timeout deploying an artifact that has deployed many times under JBoss EAP 7.3

Tags: jboss, wildfly, jboss7.x, jbpm, kie-server

I have been running PAM 7.9/JBPM 7.48 for about a year under JBOSS EAP 7.3.  My JBPM's KieServer persists using SQL Server.  I repeatedly deployed the KieServer yesterday but deploying today fails.

```
2021-12-16 15:25:53,645 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) WFLYCTL0348: Timeout after [300] seconds waiting for service container stability. Operation will roll back. Step that first updated the service container was 'full-replace-deployment' at address '[]'
2021-12-16 15:26:03,649 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) WFLYCTL0190: Step handler org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentHandlerUtil$4@74e289e9 for operation full-replace-deployment at address [] failed handling operation rollback -- java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
        at org.jboss.as.controller.OperationContextImpl.waitForRemovals(OperationContextImpl.java:523)
        at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext$Step.handleResult(AbstractOperationContext.java:1518)
```

I have already set the property to increase the timeout for the deployment but it still complains about a 5 second timeout that must be controlled by another property

```
2021-12-16 13:40:47,039 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) WFLYCTL0349: Timeout after [5] seconds waiting for service container stability while finalizing an operation. Process must be restarted. Step that first updated the service container was 'deploy' at address '[("deployment" => "kie-server.war")]'
```

I have changed the logging level to trace in order to gain all the information I can.  **How else can I debug / solve this issue?**

There are two factors that may be contributing to this, but I don't have a good approach for addressing them.

1. There was a Windows Update yesterday (likely due to the recent Log4j exploit)
2. Some people at my company are having problems connecting to the SQL Server database. I am not seeing log messages about KieServer being unable to connect to the DB, but when it cannot reaching the DB the KieServer fails to start.

Comment: In order to understand why the deployments are taking too long, enable more verbose logging for "org.jboss.as.server.deployment" or "org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner"

Comment: How do you deploy the application?

Comment: @PanagiotisChavariotis I have tried more verbose logging without much success.  I increased the timeout to 3000, which either that or changes to our VPN has made the issue seemingly go away.

Comment: @JamesR.Perkins I prefer to deploy using Business Central's deployment button associated with the project.  When that fails I use the REST UI provided with the KieServer for deploying